# How to get maximums of multiple groups based on grouping column?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an initial dataset `data` grouped by `id`:

```
id   x      y
1    0.21   1.00
1    0.34   0.66
1    0.35   0.33
1    0.94   0.00
2    0.11   1.00
2    0.90   0.66
2    0.31   0.33
2    0.33   0.00
3    0.12   1.00
3    0.34   0.71
3    0.64   0.43
3    0.89   0.14
4    0.32   1.00
4    0.33   0.66
4    0.45   0.33
4    0.76   0.00
```

I am trying to predict the maximum `y` based on variable `x` while considering the groups. First, I `train_test_split` based on the groups:

```
data_train
```

```
id   x      y
1    0.21   1.00
1    0.34   0.66
1    0.35   0.33
1    0.94   0.00
2    0.11   1.00
2    0.90   0.66
2    0.31   0.33
2    0.33   0.00
```

and

```
data_test
```

```
id   x      y
3    0.12   1.00
3    0.34   0.66
3    0.64   0.33
3    0.89   0.00
4    0.33   1.00
4    0.32   0.66
4    0.45   0.33
4    0.76   0.00
```

After training the model and applying the model on `data_test`, I get:

```
y_hat
0.65
0.33
0.13
0.00
0.33
0.34
0.21
0.08
```

I am trying to transform `y_hat` so that the maximum in each of the initial groups is `1.00`; otherwise, it is `0.00`:

```
y_hat_transform
1.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
1.00
0.00
0.00
```

How would I do that? Note that the groups can be of varying sizes.

Edit: To simplify the problem, I have `id_test` and `y_hat`, where

```
id_test
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

and I am trying to get `y_hat_transform`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    id  y
0   3   0.65
1   3   0.65
2   3   0.33
3   3   0.13
4   3   0.00
5   4   0.33
6   4   0.34
7   4   0.21
8   4   0.08
```

```
# Find max rows per group and assign them values
# I see 1.0 and 0.0 as binary so directly did it by casting to float
# transform gives new column of same size and repeated maxs per group
id_y['y_transform'] = (id_y['y'] == id_y.groupby(['id'])['y'].transform(max)).astype(float)
```